# Delete a row above where I find "DELETE"

Tags: vba

I am trying to delete 1 row above where I find work delete. This code works ok for same row deletion but I need to delete row above. I tried putting in count `-1`  but didn't work. How do I modify the code below:

```
cell.EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `.offset`, `.resize`, `join`, and `union` are very useful

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.EntireRow.offset(-1).Delete
```